# How do custom fonts keyboard apps change the style of output text?

Tags: android, string, android-softkeyboard, spannablestring

There are a lot of keyboard apps in the Play Store which can use to type in different font styles, like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fonts.emoji.fontkeyboard.free&hl=en&gl=US) app. These font styles work in any other app & they are only available for English characters.

I would like to know how do these text styles work? Is it some kind of a text span? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like [`commitText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection#commitText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) is used to insert text, it takes a `CharSequence` argument. It might work by passing an instance of `Spannable`, which is a subclass of `CharSequence`. `TypefaceSpan` can be used to change the font.

Comment: @Nicolas I already tried it & it didn't work. I don't think this is TypefaceSpan. All these keyboard apps have the same kind of font styles & they are only available for English characters. If it was TypefaceSpan, characters of other languages also should be able to change the font styles - and it is not possible. I think these are some kind of text styles available only for English characters.

Comment: https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/fancy-letters/

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you very much! This link solved my problem.